# Suddenly burning oil after heavy strain on engine, should I look for damage?

Tags: oil, dodge, smoke

This is a 1986 Dodge van with a Chrysler 318 5.2L.  Recently I was reversing through a narrow gate on snowy ground. I had to get out to check the my angle, and when I got back in I proceeded to reverse with the parking break on.

When the van hesitated I thought I was slipping on the snow, I tried to pull forward and gave it a lot of gas before it lurched and I realized the parking break was on.

Right at that point, it started blowing blue smoke big time and I parked a minute or two later.

Next time I started it, it blew  blue/white smoke for 5+ minutes. Once it warmed up and I drove it seemed normal smoke and smell wise. I drove about 300km at highway speeds.

Today I started it up and there was a small/"normal" amount of exhaust smoke and just a slight smell of burning oil, minimal enough that I generally wouldn't think twice about it (less two-stroke mower and more "old van"). It did stall once or twice at idle, but again I wouldn't call that unusual for this vehicle.

Any ideas on why I'd get oil burning in those conditions, and is it a sign of potential damage/a fault, or could it be benign and nothing to worry about?

Comment: I removed some stuff about the PCV because I ruled that out as an issue, PCV is operating correctly (according to the inspection steps in my Haynes manual)

Comment: Blue smoke is a good indicator for burning oil. It seems unlikely that heavy load damages the engine. Most likely the issues was present before, you just noticed it only now